# Responsive web design using PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, responsive-design, jsf-2.2, netbeans-8

I am going to implement web application using Java(JSF framework) and PrimeFaces . I would like to know can I create resopnsive web page design using PrimeFaces?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is: **Yes**, you can. Especially with the latest Community Edition (5.3) which has been a major step toward responsiveness.

References:

- [PrimeFaces 5.3 released](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3639)
- [PrimeFaces Blog](https://www.google.fr/search?q=primefaces%20responsive&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ylAvVoeHG8GsaffMn4gP#q=%22responsive%22%20site:blog.primefaces.org)
- [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/responsive.xhtml)

Comment: @MathieuCastets: I 'voted' to accept your edit but... Questions like this do not belong on stackoverflow, hence my 'short' answer, Posters can simply do a lot of homework themselves.